# Given a user's request for the index page ('/'), how do we intercept and run a function on the server in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Is there a way using a middleware function or some other method in Next.js to see if a user is attempting to go to the home page?

What I'm trying to do basically is intercept a user's request for the home page. Intercepting a URL request is relatively easy to do with Next.js middleware. For example, if you want to see if a user is trying to access a single page called `/login`, you can access the request url like so:

```js
export default async function middleware(req, res){

   const url = req.url;

   if (url.includes('/login')){
       // carry out action
   }

}
```

However, how can this be done for a home page URL (e.g https://fakewebsite.com/ or in development, localhost:3000)?

Comment: Does https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction not cover this?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans no it doesn't seem to. My question basically is "how do we intercept a user's request for the index page and depending on so-so data, we give the user access to the page or redirect the user to a different page or perform some other action" That documentation seems to only cover how Next.js handles CLIENT-SIDE routing

Comment: Ah. In that case, please update your post to explicitly mention that (and possibly some more details, as per the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've just made some edits and added details I believe make the question clearer.

Comment: Have you console logged `req.url`? Because it seems like a simple ```if (req.url === `/`)``` would do the trick here

Comment: I've tried that and it logged all requests made, include assets like images, JSON, etc, but I also noticed that at least in development, it logs "http://localhost:3000/". I'm thinking I might have to write a conditional that checks for NODE_ENV and if it's development, the index would be localhost and for production it would be the site base URL, very hacky and unstable but seems like the only solution until a better one is offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the middleware introduced in nextjs version 12 to accomplish this. There you can introduce a config for matching URLs and have access to user's request:
[Next.JS middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware).

The problem with what you have is that you're missing the `config` export from your middleware, inside which you can specify the `matcher`:

```js
// middleware.js

export const config = {
  matcher: '/',
}
```

This will only allow `home` requests to reach your middleware.